# Roman Empire goes to space

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, computer-puzzle

---

[image]

---

Here is the binary part for convenience:

```
01110010
10000000
10011111
10110111
```

Find what celestial objects has Roman Empire visited.

Hint 1:

> There are 3 celestial objects in total. The image contains 3 rows and each row is 1 object.

Comment: Just stuck on the binary...

Comment: @Amoz - binary is 32 bit signed integer.

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA - it's a cipher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had everything figured out right away except the binary, but have finally figured that out.
Since MW has posted a partial I will only briefly summarize answers 1 and 3 or else someone can edit them in (I'm on a phone right now).
Line 1:

> Sat. + Urn. URN is a nice tie in to the Roman theme.

Line 3:

> And + Rome + da. ROME and the Caesar shift are nice tie ins to the theme.

Line 2:

> This was the most difficult. We have a picture of a VW beetle car and four binary numbers which when converted to an unsigned 32 bit integer results in 1921032119. Again I noticed right away that this looks like the word SUCUS in A1Z26... But what could it mean? Thinking back to the Roman theme it turns out that sucus is Latin for... surprise, surprise... JUICE. Giving the final answer for line two of Betelgeuse which is a homophone of Beetle + juice. Thinking of Roman wine and grapes, juice is a nice tie in to the theme - although personally I was kind of hoping for Carpo, based off the Po River.

I gave this puzzle a plus one quite early with hopes that the final answer would make sense, and I'm happily not disappointed. Nice job.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer.

First line:

> The first date was a Saturday. That image is of an urn.
>  That means that the first celestial object is Saturn.

Third Line: (thanks a ton to caPNCApn for the help with the middle letters!)

> The first symbol is an AND logic gate. The second is a caesar cipher that encodes SPQR. SPQR stands for Senatus PopulusQue Romanus, which, in modern speak, is ancient ROME. A reverse image search shows that the last symbol is "Da" from the Javanese script.
>  Put together, that makes the third celestial body the Andromeda galaxy.

Comment: rot13(Gur tngr vf na NAQ tngr. IFGH vf n Pnrfne fuvsg sbe FCDE zrnavat EBZR. V'z thrffvat gur flzoby gb gur evtug bs gung ercerfragf QN va fbzr fpevcg.)

Comment: @caPNCApn yes, rot13(gur flzoby vf gur flyynoyr 'qn' va gur Wninarfr fpevcg)

Comment: I had figured out everything except the middle part, but I think that helps me a ton. Is it poor etiquette to post an answer using your help? (Please let me know!)

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA - if you use a partial solution provided by yet another user, I think it would be polite to make your answer a community wiki. Just my opinion.

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA It's fine to include what I shared with you and crediting me like you have is the polite thing to do. However I would recommend that you rot13(haqrefgnaq naq irevsl jung lbh cbfg. Jung lbh unir cbfgrq vf abg pbeerpg.)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will look over and correct what I've posted.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know an online rot13(ovanel gb HGS-32 havpbqr pbairegre? V unir n uhapu gung gur ovanel vf whfg n fvatyr flzoby yvxr gur "qn" jnf.)

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA: But, but, ... rot13(gur ragevrf va gur HGS-KKKVV ner [Havpbqr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) pbqr cbvagf, juvpu pna unir ng zbfg gjragl-bar ovgf. Vg pbhyq or n sbhe-ohg [HGS-rvtug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) frdhrapr, naq gur ynfg guerr ovgf fgneg jvgu bar-mreb yvxr n pbagvahngvba olgr, ohg gur svefg olgr fgnegf jvgu mreb, juvpu zrnaf vg'f n fvatyr NFPVV inyhr.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know enough about this kind of stuff yet...

Comment: The binary part is a 5 letter word.

Comment: Yeah, and given the first part, it's not hard to [guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetlejuice_(disambiguation)) which one, but I haven't been able to squeeze that out from the bits.

Comment: @MOehm lol, what? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Well, that's a homophone of (some pronunciations of) α Orionis, isn't it?

Comment: Ha ha! Thats funny. I thought it may have been some sort of rickroll-like joke I had never heard of. I clicked a link, and it was that, and I did not know what was going on. Alright, makes more sense. Now for the working out...

Comment: The binary converted to an integer is 1921032119. I am unsure where this is a coincidence, but I have noticed that rot13(rnpu gjb qvtvg frtzrag vf yrff guna 26, naq gheavat gurfr vagb yrggref tvirf 'fhphf')

Comment: It is strange how it is symmetrical.